# SONAR issue - Close this FileInputStream

Tags: java, sonarqube

How do I fix this SONAR issue?  **Close this FileInputStream.**

Thanks in advance!

```
File billFile = new File(filePath);
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        new FileInputStream(billFile), DEFAULTCHARSET));) { 

    ... 
    br.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    LOG.error(e.getMessage());              
} catch (IOException e) {
    LOG.error(e.getMessage(), e);               
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you use the [**try-with-resources**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement, you don't need to close your `BufferedReader` explicitly anymore so simply remove `br.close();` from your current code which should be enough to fix your sonar issue as a `BufferedReader` will close the underlying `InputStreamReader` on close and the `InputStreamReader` will close your `FileInputStream` on close.

---

If not enough, you could simply rewrite your code to explicitly declare your `FileInputStream` as a resource of your *try-with-resources* statement like below:

```
try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(billFile);
     Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(fis, DEFAULTCHARSET);
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader) {
     ...
```

---

If it still doesn't work make sure that sonar is properly configured for Java 7 and above otherwise it won't be aware of the *try-with-resources* statement which would lead to this violation raise.

Comment: Thanks.  I have this issue in another portion of the code as below. This is the full function and there is no br.close() in it.

`try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
    new FileInputStream(tmpFile), DEFAULTCHARSET));) {
   String eachLine;

   while ((eachLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    ctr = eachLine;

   }
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
   LOG.error(e);  
  } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
   LOG.error(e1);
  } catch (IOException e) {
   LOG.error(e);
  
  }`

Comment: I think so yes if not define it as a resource as proposed in the response update

Answer (score 1):

It might be the case that you're using an outdated SONAR version or rule-set. Check the version. (`try-with-resources` was introduced with Java 7)

Comment: We are using SONAR v5.6.3.  We had this issue in several files and we resolved with the `try-with-resources` and they all went away except these.