# Close this "FileOutputStream" sonar again

Tags: java, sonarqube

I am having the trouble of **close the  "FileOutputStream"** from sonar . Eventhough  I closed the file. From the document of Sonar I don´t understand the error. 
I looked at the post 
[SONAR issue - Close this FileInputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41960463/sonar-issue-close-this-fileinputstream).
This also not solving my problem.

```
 public void trainL2lSupport(String training_path, String model_path) throws Exception {
            BasicConfigurator.configure();

            String[] options = { "-s 1" };
            FileOutputStream ms = new FileOutputStream(model_path); // This one is producing the error.

            classifier.setOptions(options);
            logger.info(msg + classifier.globalInfo());
            loader.setFile(new File(training_path));
            Instances data_set = loader.getDataSet();
            data_set.setClassIndex(data_set.numAttributes() - 1);
            classifier.buildClassifier(data_set);
            Evaluation evaluation = new Evaluation(data_set);
            evaluation.crossValidateModel(classifier, data_set, 40, new Random(1));
            logger.info(evaluation.toSummaryString());
            logger.info(msg1 + timer.stop());

            // oos = new ObjectOutputStream(ms);
            try {


            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(ms);
            oos.writeObject(classifier);
            oos.flush();

            oos.close();


            logger.info(msg3+ evaluation.toSummaryString());
            logger.info(msg1 + timer.stop());

            logger.info("File closed safetly");
            } catch(Exception e) {

            }

            finally {
                ms.close();

            }

        }
```

How to solve it ?

Comment: Put declatation inside the try as object ms is not used before try  FileOutputStream ms = new FileOutputStream(model_path); // This one is producing the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the try-with-resources statement.

If an exception is thrown from any of the lines of code before the try block, the FileOutputStream is never closed. Hence the Sonar warning.

Also, indent your code, don't catch Exception (you should have another warning for that), and don't ignore exceptions like you're doing.

Comment: try-with-resources statement. an example please

Comment: Seriously? Use google. Jeez. Is it really that complex, for a software developer, to type "try-with-resources" in your location bar, hit enter, and click on the first link?

Comment: It is not for me. It is for other people. try(ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream (new FileOutputStream(model_path))){
     
   }

Comment: Other people reading this answer should be able to do that as well.

Comment: Someone who is unable to google "try-with-resources" should be banned from writing software.

Comment: A link for people who are too lazy to Google :-) - https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/89/exceptions-and-exception-handling/1581/the-try-with-resources-statement#t=201705261246312921409