# Sonarqube - performance issue as Method uses a FileInputStream constructor, what are the better alternatives?

Tags: java, file, sonarqube, inputstream, fileinputstream

Here is my code :

```
        KeyStore truststore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        truststore.load(new FileInputStream(TRUSTSTORE_FILE), 
                                           TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD.toCharArray()); //sonarqube issue
```

Which is the most suitable InputStream for getting this done?

Here is the full error :

```
This method creates and uses a java.io.FileInputStream or java.io.FileOutputStream object. Unfortunately both of these classes implement a finalize method, which means that objects created will likely hang around until a full garbage collection occurs, which will leave excessive garbage on the heap for longer, and potentially much longer than expected.
```

Do I really need to switch to :

```
InputStream is = java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(myfile.toPath());
```

I am not comfortable with this one.

Comment: Could you please detail the received Sonarqube issue?

Comment: Wrap it in a `BufferedInputStream`.

Comment: Wrap it in a try-with-resources so it will be closed at the end of the block. The error message is complaining that the file might be open a long time.

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström I read your comment a bit late, can you give it as answer; you might copy mine.

Answer (score 3):

Wrap it in a try-with-resources so it will be closed at the end of the block. The error message is complaining that the file might be open a long time.

```
try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream(TRUSTSTORE_FILE)) {
    KeyStore truststore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
    truststore.load(in, TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD.toCharArray());
} // Automatically closes in.
```

This frees system resources (a file handle) and allows others to overwrite the truststore file.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it doesn't solve my issue. I have updated the complete error

Comment: Ah, that's too bad. I would disagree with SonarQube's error if you take care to close the InputStream like this. Unfortunately i don't know a solution other than `Files.newInputStream`.

Comment: I found [this answer that might be related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41960492). It talks about configuring SonarQube to be aware of the try-with-resources statement.